# Retrieving the average from an optional date field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to find the average amount of task complete in a category based on if an optional date time field is set.

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='hello world')


Task(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I can find the total, and the count with this query

```
Task.objects.values('category')\
.annotate(
   complete=Sum(
      Case(
        When(completed_at__isnull=False, then=1), default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField())
      ),
   count=Count('id'))
```

That would give me a list like so:

```
[{'category': fk, 'complete': 0, count: 5}]
```

And I could just iterate over the array in python and find the average.
But I would like to do this in the query.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? `complete / count` for each category? across all categories? Or are you looking for the (sum of complete) / (count of category)?

Comment: I'm trying to find the average complete per category.

Comment: Why not iterate in python? it's fast, and less data to retrieve from the DB

Comment: [dict({'average':float(x['complete'])/x['count']},**x) for x in L]

Comment: It isn't fast, it's really slow compared to doing it in the database.